# How to prevent clearing my password when login form is submitted?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I'm using the basic configuration of ember-simple-auth. When I click submit, request is gone to backend but my password field becomes empty. My username field is still filled.

My template: login.emblem

```
form.submit='authenticate'
  Ember.TextField id='identification' valueBinding='identification'
  Ember.TextField id='password' type='password' valueBinding='password'

  button type='submit'
    | Login
```

Controller: login.js

```
import Ember from "ember";
import LoginControllerMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/login-controller-mixin';
export default Ember.Controller.extend(LoginControllerMixin, {
  authenticator: "simple-auth-authenticator:oauth2-password-grant",
});
```

Route: login.js

```
import Ember from "ember";
import UnauthenticatedRouteMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/unauthenticated-route-mixin';
 export default Ember.Route.extend(UnauthenticatedRouteMixin, {
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using [`LoginControllerMixin`'s `authenticate` action](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/packages/ember-simple-auth/lib/simple-auth/mixins/login-controller-mixin.js#L47) you can simply define your own:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticationControllerMixin from 'simple-auth/Authentication-controller-mixin';

export default Ember.Controller.extend(AuthenticationControllerMixin, {
  authenticator: 'simple-auth-authenticator:oauth2-password-grant',
  actions: {
    authenticate: function() {
      var data = this.getProperties('identification', 'password');
      return this._super(data);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: It saves password but doesn't run request to backend at all. Should I add it myself? As far as i understand  this._super(data); should run request to backend. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, the super call invokes the authenticator which will send a request to the backend.

Comment: I copy your code but it doesn't send request to backend at all. If I add LoginControllerMixin and write this function - then it works....

Comment: Ah sorry, you have to mixin the AuthenticationControllerMixin instead. I updated the answer.